# CTE with multiple subqueries inside of it

Tags: sql, db2

I am wondering if anyone knows why i cant convert the below code into a CTE?

Is it because it has too many sub queries? Please assist. I plan on using the results from the below query as temp table to join with.

When i run the code below without adding the "WITH CTE as (" syntax it runs perfectly, however once i add the syntax i get an error:

> BIC00004. DAL010059. An error occurred while accessing the database:
>   ILLEGAL SYMBOL "". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL
>   ARE: SELECT ( ,. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.17.29 Extended
>   error description is: An unexpected token "" was
>   found following "SELECT ( ,". Expected tokens may include: "{2}"

I appreciate the help.

```
    SELECT F.PBC_NUMBER, F.EY_SAMPLE, F.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, F.SITE_ID, F.NIIN, MIN(F.CAT) AS CAT
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT E.PBC_NUMBER, E.EY_SAMPLE, E.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, E.SITE_ID, E.NIIN, CONCAT(E.TRX_DT, E.SEQ_TIME) AS CAT
        FROM (
            SELECT C.PBC_NUMBER, C.EY_SAMPLE, C.NIIN, C.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, C.SITE_ID, C.TRX_DT, MIN(D.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM (
                SELECT A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDRVENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HERV'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDJFENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID IN ('HEJF', 'HEJG')
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDCNENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HECN'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDEENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'EGDE'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDWGENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018226' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEWG'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDAAENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018233' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEAA'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDKENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YKBK'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDPJENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YYAL'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME) AS C
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDRVENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HERV'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDJFENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID IN ('HEJF', 'HEJG')
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDCNENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HECN'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDEENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'EGDE'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDWGENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018226' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEWG'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDAAENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018233' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEAA'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDKENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YKBK'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
                UNION

                SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
                FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DDPJENVR.ATR B
                ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
                WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YYAL'
                GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT) AS D


            ON C.NIIN = D.NIIN AND C.SITE_ID = D.SITE_ID AND C.TRX_DT = D.TRX_DT AND C.SEQ_TIME = D.SEQ_TIME
            GROUP BY C.PBC_NUMBER, C.EY_SAMPLE, C.TRX_DT, C.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, C.SITE_ID, C.NIIN) AS E
            ORDER BY E.SITE_ID) AS F
            GROUP BY F.PBC_NUMBER, F.EY_SAMPLE, F.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, F.SITE_ID, F.NIIN
```

Comment: What for? I don't think it will get simpler.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I originally had it so that there was a Min aggregate on TRX_DT field and MIN aggregate on the SEQ_TIME field, however i was told by a coworker that i would need to run both separately and concatenate them to form a unique value. So the CTE would hold the combined fields and than Left outer join with another table. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @AaronDietz the error i get is : BIC00004. DAL010059. An error occurred while accessing the database:
 ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<END-OF-STATEMENT>". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: SELECT ( ,. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.17.29
 Extended error description is: 
 An unexpected token "<END-OF-STATEMENT>" was found following "SELECT ( ,".  Expected tokens may include:  "{2}".

Comment: That's quite an error.  Your syntax is `with cte as (yourQuery) select * from cte` ?

Comment: @AaronDietz That is correct. I am fairly new to SQL. Could it be just an error in logic from the syntax? Would that explain why it works when i remove the [with cte as (yourQuery) select * from cte] ?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `db2` syntax to say.  Most likely it's a syntax error, but it's possible that CTEs in `db2` don't allow something that your query is doing.  Maybe try removing the `ORDER BY` in your derived table `F`.  Most dbs wouldn't allow that... I doubt that is it though.  Looks like this has some info on your error message: https://www.idug.org/p/fo/et/thread=35174

Comment: CCP, I work with DB2 all the time. If you post the `CREATE TABLE ...` statement, I can transform it to CTE for you.

Comment: The error message does not match the query you posted.

Comment: `I originally had it so that there was a Min aggregate on TRX_DT field and MIN aggregate on the SEQ_TIME field, however i was told by a coworker that i would need to run both separately and concatenate them to form a unique value.`  Both of you are wrong: you're getting times that are unrelated to the dates.  You need to convert it to the combined timestamp first, _then_ call `MIN` on it.  Also, why do you have so many identical schemas?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The date fields are in CHAR. So are you saying to concatenate them first and then use a MIN aggregate? There are so many identical schemas because I am fairly new to SQL and my employer needed results ASAP. In other words, i panicked and tried to write something up quick.

Comment: ...Well, hopefully it's in a SARGable format (ie, ISO: `YYYY-MM-DD`), or you're in trouble when you do the minimum.  _Ideally_, you would be storing the combined timestamp type in the first place.  Failing that, assuming your date/time are in a recognizable format, `TIMESTAMP` will give you a usable combined value.  And, except in certain multi-consumer scenarios (which probably don't apply here), you generally don't want multiple identical schemas - you forget which piece is stored where, or require meta knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the ORDER BY as stated by Aaron Dietz and was able to query.

```
` SELECT F.PBC_NUMBER, F.EY_SAMPLE, F.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, F.SITE_ID, F.NIIN, MIN(F.CAT) AS CAT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT E.PBC_NUMBER, E.EY_SAMPLE, E.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, E.SITE_ID, E.NIIN, CONCAT(E.TRX_DT, E.SEQ_TIME) AS CAT
    FROM (
        SELECT C.PBC_NUMBER, C.EY_SAMPLE, C.NIIN, C.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, C.SITE_ID, C.TRX_DT, MIN(D.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
        FROM (
            SELECT A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDRVENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HERV'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDJFENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID IN ('HEJF', 'HEJG')
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDCNENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HECN'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDEENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'EGDE'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDWGENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018226' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEWG'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDAAENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018233' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEAA'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDKENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YKBK'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, MIN(B.TRX_DT) AS TRX_DT, A.NIIN, B.SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDPJENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YYAL'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.SEQ_TIME) AS C
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDRVENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HERV'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDJFENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID IN ('HEJF', 'HEJG')
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDCNENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HECN'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDEENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'EGDE'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDWGENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018226' AND '2018229') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEWG'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDAAENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018233' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'HEAA'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDKENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YKBK'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT
            UNION

            SELECT  A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, B.TRX_DT, A.NIIN, MIN(B.SEQ_TIME) AS SEQ_TIME
            FROM KCA0001.TRANS12 A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DDPJENVR.ATR B
            ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID AND B.NIIN = A.NIIN AND (B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018232' AND '2018236') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A', 'D9A')
            WHERE A.SITE_ID = 'YYAL'
            GROUP BY A.PBC_NUMBER, A.EY_SAMPLE, A.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, A.SITE_ID, A.NIIN, B.MED_STA_CD, B.TRX_DT) AS D


        ON C.NIIN = D.NIIN AND C.SITE_ID = D.SITE_ID AND C.TRX_DT = D.TRX_DT AND C.SEQ_TIME = D.SEQ_TIME
        GROUP BY C.PBC_NUMBER, C.EY_SAMPLE, C.TRX_DT, C.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, C.SITE_ID, C.NIIN) AS E
        ) AS F
        GROUP BY F.PBC_NUMBER, F.EY_SAMPLE, F.DISTRIBUTION_CENTER, F.SITE_ID, F.NIIN `
```